# Question on Borel sets in set-valued map

Tags: measure-theory

$(T,\mathcal{T})$ is a measurable space ,$X$ is a metric complete separable space, and $F$ is a multifunction from $T$ to $X$ with closed valued.

How to prove that if $F^{-1}_+(B)=\lbrace t\in T, F(t)\cap B \neq \emptyset \rbrace \in \mathcal{T}$ for every Borel set $B$ ,then

$F^{-1}_+(C)=\lbrace t\in T, F(t)\cap C \neq \emptyset \rbrace \in \mathcal{T}$ for every closed set $C$

Comment: yes yes yes  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider a topological space $(X,\cal T)$, closed sets are measurable for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.